# How can I make all of the contents of my DIV appear on one line?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following:

```
        <ul class="right">
            <li>
                <div class="hdr_msg">Welcome Visitor!</div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Users", null, new {
                    title = "Login", 
                    rel = "nofollow" 
                })<div class="hdr_msg"> or </div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users", null, new {
                    title = "Register your ID", 
                    rel = "nofollow" 
                })
            </li>
        </ul>
```

which makes the following source code:

```
        <ul class="right">
            <li style="float: left">
                <div class="hdr_msg">Welcome Visitor!</div>

                <a href="/Users/Login" rel="nofollow" title="Login">Login</a><div class="hdr_msg"> or </div>
                <a href="/Users/Register" rel="nofollow" title="Register your ID">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

My problem is that I want all of the details to appear on one line. I would like to see "Welcome Visitor! Login or Register" on one line but now it all flows vertically dow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `<span>` instead of `<div>`:

```
<li>
    <span class="hdr_msg">Welcome Visitor!</span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Users", null, new {
        title = "Login", 
        rel = "nofollow" 
    })
    <span class="hdr_msg"> or </span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users", null, new {
        title = "Register your ID", 
        rel = "nofollow" 
    })
</li>
```

Another possibility is to keep the divs but in your CSS files to apply them the `inline` display rule:

```
.hdr_msg {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a wrapping `<span>` around the whole text. Dont use one `<span>` to inster just the `or` between Login and Register.

Heres my suggestion:

```
    <ul class="right">
        <li>
            <span class="hdr_msg">Welcome Visitor!
            @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Users", null, new {
                title = "Login", 
                rel = "nofollow" 
            }) or 
            @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users", null, new {
                title = "Register your ID", 
                rel = "nofollow" 
            })
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```